# The Hölder condition with the negative exponent $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \frac{1}{|x-y|}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

> Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\forall \ x, y: x \neq y \to$ $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \frac{1}{|x-y|}$

I need to prove that $f$ is

> A) bounded
>
> B) continuous
>
> C) differentiable
>
> D) non decreasing

on $\mathbb{R}$

Could you please give me any hints?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If $|x-y|<\delta$, then $\frac1{|x-y|}>\frac1{\delta}$. So you can't do B) this way...

Comment: @MundronSchmidt yes, It's true. Thank you

Comment: For A), notice that the expression on the right is bounded above by 1, so what can you do with that?

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite why? if for example $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and $y = 0$ then $\frac{1}{|x-y|} = 2 > 1$

Comment: @DF yes sorry i don’t know what went through my head

Comment: @DF did you try experimenting with various functions to try to make an educated guess?

Comment: @DF you can still use it by splitting R in say everything except (-1,1) and (-1,1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix a point $a \in \mathbb R$. The stated hypothesis tells you that
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = f(a).$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes. Thank you a lot!